# How to prevent iOS 5 from showing the status bar even though UIStatusBarHidden is YES?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, statusbar

Some users reported that iOS 5 sometimes shows the status bar.

In my Info.plist the UIStatusBarHidden key is YES, and I never mess around with the status bar in code.

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: I've just started developing a new project with SDK 5.0, (Target 4.0) and have the same problem. I set UIStatusBarHidden = YES in plist OR call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationNone]; and anyway the status bar appear on each subseqeunt screen opening. Notify me please if you find a working solution.

Comment: see my reply below. I did manage to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the entry in the Info.plist should be enough to hide it, but you can try doing it programmatically with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

when your app starts up.

Comment: setStatusBarHidden:animated:
(Deprecated in iOS 3.2. Use setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: instead.)

Comment: @KostiantynSokolinskyi use setStatusBarHidden:YES instead

Answer (score 6):

I think the above method is deprecated in iOS5, I would use this one instead:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!

I did set property in the plist but was still getting status bar visible after pushing a view controller into the navigation stack or opening UIImagePickerController:
(I use Xcode 4.2 (SDK 5.0) and iOS 5.0.1).

Here it is (put the code in every View Controller you don't need status bar to be visible):

Set self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
in

```
- (id)initWithNibName: (NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle: (NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
```

call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
```

Then it works in case of pushing controllers through navigation stack as well as using UIImagePickerController (both taken picture or cancelled).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`xcode 4.5` gives you **an check Option to hide status bar** on summary page

1. Go to Target of project.
2. Open sumaary and then check the Hide StatusBar Option..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 3rd party frameworks that show the status bar?