# Hide Status Bar from iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios

I want my app to not have the status bar at all! I have tried using the .plst

I have tried everything in here [Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)
and also in here
[How to prevent iOS 5 from showing the status bar even though UIStatusBarHidden is YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615377/how-to-prevent-ios-5-from-showing-the-status-bar-even-though-uistatusbarhidden-i)

Can someone go into extreme detail to help me? I am using XCode 5 if that helps. I just want the status bar to be gone from the app! 
Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7/18549998#18549998

Comment: What kind of UIViewController are you setting as UIWindow RootViewController?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## iOS 7

In your Info.plist file add key **View controller-based status bar appearance** with value **NO**. And, add key **Status bar is initially hidden** with value **YES**.

Comment: This should work in iOS 7. Are you sure that you added both keys?.

Comment: HA! i had to make a new iOS 7 project to make it work but i am fine with that! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

To hide the status bar after the app has completely launched, change it programmatically by adding this line to your app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

If you set animated to YES then the status bar will disappear by fading out. One question, why do you want to delete the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

in your "*project_name*-Info.plist" file, add a key named "Status bar is initially hidden" and  then set the value to "YES". that will always hide the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
//viewDidload
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
// iOS 7
[self prefersStatusBarHidden];
[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
// iOS 6
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}


// Add this Method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried this:**
click on .xib file -> attribute inspector -> change 'Status Bar' to 'None'
(refer attached image)
[image]

Comment: yes i have but the status bar still comes up in the simulator and on my phone. i am using storyboads if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Open your application Info.plist file and add the following lines:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your view controller

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```