# Status bar gets hidden when picking up image imagepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

My requirement for the app is to show status bar through out the app.On certain Viewcontroller I am calling Image picker. on click on buttonImage, When current viewcontroller disappears and camera appears, status bar gets hidden that actually shifts navigation bar slightly upwards. the status bar and navigation bar resumes after completion of image pickup.
How can I keep status bar unaffected?

Comment: Do you want to show status bar on the Camera and UIImagePicker View's ?

Comment: @arpana sakpal what you want ?

Comment: I think this [Hide Status Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018391/hide-status-bar-from-iphone-application) link will helps in your case.

Comment: I just want to show status bar on UIimagepicker ViewController

Comment: Hide status bar works for other all view controllers only when uiview controller navigating to camera its hiding status bar for a while which reappears later after image picker did finish.

Comment: @ArpanaSakpal When you open camera using UIImagePickerController,iOS SDK does'n allowed to status bar.if you want to show stausbar than you follow this [link](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder)

Answer (score 1):

May not be correct way to do it but after trying many answers, I just cancelled the animation of push Viewcontroller. I did in this way

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.allowsEditing=YES;
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

in `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];}`

this just hides the status bar shifting

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}`

Please right down this code in your respective class as UIImagePickerController dismiss will call this function and your status bar will not dissappear anymore.