# UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarHidden=YES; 'statusBarHidden' is deprecated in iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarHidden=YES;
```

is deprecated in iOS 13. The compiler says to 'use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead'.

How/Where do you get the handle to statusBarManager? It's not in UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows.

Comment: Are you using an older version of swift? `UIApplication.sharedApplication` was changed to `UIApplication.shared`

Comment: Thanks but using objective-c as per the tags underneath the question.

Comment: ah gotcha. didn't notice that. i'll remove my answer.

Comment: There's a pointer to your solution right in the error message: "... of the window scene instead"

Comment: `UIViewControllers`'s `prefersStatusBarHidden` isn't deprecated

Comment: #Gareon - I appreciate the pointer to the error msg. I have done lots of research around this and at a loss. Hence me asking a question on Stackoverflow to get further help.

Comment: #Cy-4AH - Thanks. But I wish to set the status bar as hidden. prefersStatusBarHidden is read onle.

Comment: You can write `@property (nonatomic) BOOL prefersStatusBarHidden` in your's subclasses

Comment: Gareon is trying to say, that `UIWindow` and `UIWindowScene` is two different things.

Comment: #Cy-4AH Thanks but a warning appears: Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'prefersStatusBarHidden' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property

Comment: Just write `@synthesize prefersStatusBarHidden;` in implementation

Comment: Thanks but don't understand how just creating a variable and making it writable actually makes any changes. Found an answer as below, so many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: You become able to use view controller's `prefersStatusBarHidden` instead of window's `sharedApplication`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Status Bar from iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018391/hide-status-bar-from-iphone-application)

Comment: No. The status bar was still there. I found the answer eventually as below. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove all instances which is deprecated in iOS13:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarHidden=YES;
```

Instead add this to the plist file:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: I was thinking that you need to change it dynamically 